# Attached property doesn't work unless I put "Property" at the end of its name

Tags: c#, wpf, attached-properties

I have a simple attached property:

```
class TestAttached
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TestProperty", typeof(string), typeof(TestAttached));

    public static string GetTest(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (string)d.GetValue(TestProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTest(DependencyObject d, string value)
    {
        d.SetValue(TestProperty, value);
        TextBox tb = d as TextBox;
        tb.Text = value;
    }
}
```

and

```
<TextBox local:TestAttached.Test="Test" />
```

Nothing happens and no breakpoint is hit (which I put at `SetTest`) unless I set the first parameter of `RegisterAttached` to "TestProperty" instead of "Test". No tutorial I have found, including the [one on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753957%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), does this, and as far as I can tell, my code is the same as theirs and should work. What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Dependency property is get/set via XAML, wrapper method never gets called. So, you should avoid writing code there.

From [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx):

> Current WPF implementation of the **XAML processor behavior for property
>   setting bypasses the wrappers entirely**, you should not put any
>   additional logic into the set definitions of the wrapper for your
>   custom dependency property. If you put such logic in the set
>   definition, then the logic will not be executed when the property is
>   set in XAML rather than in code.

Instead you can use **`PropertyChangedCallback`** in case you want to put some code on property change of DP.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Test", typeof(string),
                                         typeof(TestAttached),
                                         new PropertyMetadata(TestChanged));

public static void TestChanged(DependencyObject d,
                               DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Place your code here
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

> But if I change the name to "TestProperty" then the breakpoint gets
>   hit at SetTest.

Reason for that is: **`Test`** now behaves as **normal CLR property**. Property is nothing but instead Get/Set methods when you crack it down to IL code.

That's why setter gets hit like it does for normal CLR property.

If you try to bind with some other property,

```
<TextBox local:TestAttached.Test="{Binding SomeCLRProperty}" />
```

you will see application crashes stating:

> A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'SetTest' property of type 'TextBox'.
>   A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a
>   DependencyObject.

Comment: But if I change the name to "TestProperty" then the breakpoint gets hit at `SetTest`

Comment: @Aron - No, third argument is for owner type and since it's an attached property. So, owner will be containing class. So, it should be `typeof(TestAttached)`.

Comment: @RohitVats could you also make a note of the line `TextBox tb = d as TextBox;`http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2013/09/19/casting-vs-quot-as-quot-embracing-exceptions.aspx

Comment: I was basing it largely on [this post](http://digitaltapestry.wordpress.com/2008/08/20/the-first-rule-of-wpf/) which is where most that stuff came from, but it was also me just trying to create a SSCCE... Oh well

Comment: @Aron - That part is not relevant to this answer because OP is interested in why DP doesn't work. `Casting vs "as"` is completely different topic. Let the link remain here in the comments (obviously might be helpful for OP) so that answer remains precise for the future readers.

Comment: @Rohit Vans is there a difference between what you did, `new PropertyMetadata(TestChanged)`, and `new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(TestChanged))`?

Comment: No, they are one and same thing. Other is just more verbose way to write it out. Both will work same.